# VBA Access: Else nunca es tenido en cuenta

Tags: vba, ms-access

Incialmente tenía el siguiente código:

```vb
Private Sub btn_Cambiar_Click()

On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim CambiarContraseña As String
    Dim coincidenContraseñas As Variant

    If coincidenContraseñas = DLookup("[Contraseña]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña] =" & Me.txt_Contraseña) Then

            CambiarContraseña = _
            "UPDATE tbl_Usuarios SET Contraseña = txt_Contraseña_Nueva.value WHERE ID_Usuario = txt_Usuario"

            DoCmd.RunSQL CambiarContraseña

            MsgBox ("Changed")

            txt_Contraseña = Null
            txt_Contraseña_Nueva = Null

        Else
            MsgBox "lala"
    End If

End Sub
```

Y sólo me tenía en cuenta la condición incial, mas no lo del else, que sería en caso de que fuera diferente el texto de la contraseña, así que incluí específicamente eso con una nueva condición mediante el `IfElse`así:

Private Sub btn_Cambiar_Click()
On Error Resume Next

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim CambiarContraseña As String
Dim coincidenContraseñas As Variant

If coincidenContraseñas = DLookup("[Contraseña]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña] =" & Me.txt_Contraseña) Then

        CambiarContraseña = _
        "UPDATE tbl_Usuarios SET Contraseña = txt_Contraseña_Nueva.value WHERE ID_Usuario = txt_Usuario"

        DoCmd.RunSQL CambiarContraseña

        MsgBox ("Contraseña cambiada")

        txt_Contraseña = Null
        txt_Contraseña_Nueva = Null

    ElseIf coincidenContraseñas = DLookup("[Contraseña]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña] <>" & Me.txt_Contraseña) Then

        MsgBox "Contraseña Incorrecta"
        txt_Contraseña.SetFocus
        txt_Contraseña_Nueva = Null

        Exit Sub

    Else
        MsgBox "lulu"
End If
```

End Sub

Pero con el código anterior sigo teniendo el mismo inconveniente que a pesar de que sea igual o diferente lo del `txt_Contraseña`

Aprecio cualquier ayuda o sugerencia respecto a esto, gracias.

Comment: Borra `On Error Resume Next`. Esta línea oculta los errores, pero se siguen produciendo. Ejecútalo en modo depurador paso a paso y así miras por qué no se produce nunca lo que quieres.

Comment: Lo he borrado y correguí algo de la sintaxis del if y ya ha funcionado. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que correguir la sintaxis de la condición inicial del `If` y no es necesario declarar una variable `Variant`, también sobra anañadir otra condición, es decir, otro `If` para expresar lo opuesto a la condición primera:

```vb
Private Sub btn_Cambiar_Click()
On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'CurrentDb.Execute dbFailOnError

    If (DLookup("[Contraseña]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña] <>'" & Me.txt_Contraseña.Value & "' ")) Then
        MsgBox "¡La contraseña no coincide!"
        Me.txt_Contraseña.SetFocus

    Else
            CambiarContraseña = _
            "UPDATE tbl_Usuarios SET Contraseña = txt_Contraseña_Nueva.value WHERE ID_Usuario = txt_Usuario"

            DoCmd.RunSQL CambiarContraseña

            MsgBox ("Contraseña Cambiada")

            txt_Contraseña = Null
            txt_Contraseña_Nueva = Null
    End If

End Sub
```